# Mongo Atlas Issue, can't properly choose my database

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm using mongo atlas and its creating the database with the name test by default, and only passing my information to that database as well.

I've changed my URI and its still doing the same, any ideas how I can tell atlas where to pass my data to?

This is my URI:

```
mongodb+srv://name:password@cluster0.rn6mt.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: well, I updated the name and password, just didn't want to include it in stackoverflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'myFirstDatabase' with the name of the database you created in atlas.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).